# Mingw and libraw results in undefined reference

Tags: c++, mingw

Is anyone using libraw with mingw? I am trying to compile a program and get the following errors:

```
obj\Release\inc\img\cimg.o:cimg.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6LibRawC1Ej'|
obj\Release\inc\img\cimg.o:cimg.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6LibRaw9open_fileEPKcx'|
obj\Release\inc\img\cimg.o:cimg.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6LibRaw6unpackEv'|
obj\Release\inc\img\cimg.o:cimg.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6LibRaw13dcraw_processEv'|
obj\Release\inc\img\cimg.o:cimg.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6LibRaw20dcraw_make_mem_imageEPi'|
obj\Release\inc\img\cimg.o:cimg.cpp|| undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6LibRaw7recycleEv'|
obj\Release\inc\img\cimg.o:cimg.cpp:(.text$_ZN6LibRawD1Ev[LibRaw::~LibRaw()]+0xf)||undefined reference to `_imp___ZN6LibRaw7recycleEv'|
||=== Build finished: 7 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I added libraw.a to my project. Can't figure the problem out.
Has anyone an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From those symbol names, it looks like you're trying to compile against a DLL version of libraw (hinted at by the `_imp___` prefix).  Check your libraw header files and make sure that the function names don't have anything like `__declspec(dllimport)` or `__attribute__((dllimport))` in front of them.  These are sometimes hidden by a macro definition, so check the header files to see if there's another macro you can define which will cause it not to use that attribute in the function prototypes.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I looked into the headerfiles and there were these dllimport things. Anyways with a Preprocessor define LIBRAW_NODLL=1 I got it working, but now i ran into another problem which I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12921911/mingw-libgcc-s-sjlj-1-dll-is-missing