# Mingw libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing

Tags: c++, windows-7, mingw

I'm trying to compile a program in codeblocks using mingw. I had to include libw2_32.a that I don't get any compiler errors. The program compiles fine but when I want to run it, it says that libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll is missing.

I searched for this dll in my mingw installation but the only dll I found is: libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You have to use -static-libgcc while compiling with mingw’s g++ to eliminate the dependency on LIBGCC_S_SJLJ-1.DLL. You can do that by adding static-libgcc to the linker flags.

I found this info in this post:
http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/39639-MinGW-w64-dependency-on-LIBGCC_S_SJLJ-1-DLL

Comment: thanks for the link, that wasn't my problem but i saw in the link, that this description is for mingw 64. this pointed me in the right direction. i compiled the program using the 32 bit mingw compiler instead of the 64 bit compiler.

Comment: Sorry where do you add `static-libgcc` to the linker flags in codeblocks?